# moderncv \cventry remove dots at the end of line

Tags: moderncv

Im using the template for moderncv, and i want to remove the dots at the end of the line of `\cventry`, can someone recode the command for me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{1990--2015}{Wisdom}{School of life}{Earth}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also, providing some basic code is a good start, but this is not a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) because it doesn't compile. The `moderncv` class requires some missing arguments in order to compile. Can you please convert the code you have posted in your question into an MWE? It will make it much easier to help you since we can then just copy and paste your code into our editors.

Answer (score 24):

In order to change this, you will need to change how `\cventry` is defined.

`\cventry` is defined as:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \savebox{\cventryyearbox}{%
    \hspace*{2\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \hintstyle{#2}}%
  \setlength{\cventrytitleboxwidth}{\widthof{\usebox{\cventryyearbox}}}%
  \setlength{\cventrytitleboxwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\cventrytitleboxwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
    \parbox[t]{\cventrytitleboxwidth}{%
      \strut%
      {\bfseries#3}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
      .\strut}%
    \usebox{\cventryyearbox}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{%
      \newline{}%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\maincolumnwidth}%
        \small%
        #7%
      \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

You can use the package [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to patch this command in the preamble of your document. If you look at the definition above, you will see that the relevant thing to change is the line that says `.\strut}%`.

`xpatch` provides the command `\xpatchcmd`. The syntax for the command is:

```
\xpatchcmd{⟨command⟩}{⟨search⟩}{⟨replace⟩}{⟨success⟩}{⟨failure⟩}
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\name{John}{Doe}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{1990--2015}{Wisdom}{School of life}{Earth}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That's a very useful package!! :D

Comment: How could I remove the comma too?

Comment: @nilon Which comma? Depending on which comma you want to remove, the easiest thing to do is probably just to copy the `\cventry` macro and redefine it in your preamble. See [Remove comma from moderncv's \cventry](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86532/32888).

Answer (score 6):

This also works for me:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\cventry{.}{}{}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

As note, starting from the answer of @AdamLiter, you need to consider the `\moderncvstyle` used. For example, by using `\moderncvstyle{casual}`, reading inside the file `moderncvstylecasual.sty` (located in *'/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv'*, considering *TeXlive 2019*), you will see `\moderncvbody{1}` that means `moderncvbodyi.sty`. So, inside this last one, you can take the definition of `\cventry`, that in this case is:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

In your `tex` file `preamble` you can now copy it, changing `.\strut%` with `\strut%`, and I suggest you to give another name to this **new command** (for example `\cventrynofinaldotcasual`) to not overwrite the original one but to use this *custom* `\cventry` only when you need it, like so:

```
\newcommand*{\cventrynofinaldotcasual}[7][.25em]{% ROW CHANGED: NOTE '\newcommand', NOT '\renewcommand'!
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut% ROW CHANGED!
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Now you can use the new command in the `body` of your `tex` file like so:

```
\cventrynofinaldotcasual[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optional: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description} % OUTPUT WITHOUT FINAL DOT!
```